# Generate Report in Plugin (Dynamics 365)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

i gust curious maybe someone heard about solution how to get Report (SSRS Report) in Plugin (i want to export it in pdf from CRM and save in Sharepoint).

I have tried following solution:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/247210/how-to-run-the-crm-report-through-sdk?pifragment-97030=1#responses

this one is not working anymore because of authentication. I tried to authentificate my user in WebClient inside plugin but no luck. Maybe someone know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent article/blog posted by [**Bob Guidinger**](https://bguidinger.com/) for Generating Report and sending Email for D365 Online.

Once you get first step running, you can extend it to perform you specific operation.

Blog mentioned about Azure function and plugin (combination).

[Scheduling Reports in Dynamics 365 - Part 1](https://bguidinger.com/blog/scheduling-reports-dynamics-365-part-1)

I tried this for one of my project and it worked fine with me. This shall be a bit learning curve if you do not know how to create azure functions and some small parts.

Happy Coding!!

Make sure to upvote, Accept if this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try it :) Looks promising

Comment: if it helps please mark it as solved, it will help others as well.

Comment: I have tried it and no luck ... Looks like Azure changed from that time and they don't have same configuration. I'm trying to find solution but i will wright here when finish :)

Comment: @masta I also have a similar requirement. Need to send out SSRS report from Dynamics 365 Online via plugin in PDF format. Please help us know how you get it working?